# Not able to curl to my VM when ssh is working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, curl, flask

I'm trying to run a simple flask server on an Ubuntu VM.

I can ssh into it,with `myuser@123.456.789`, but if I execute `curl 123.456.789:8000` I get an operation timeout, even though the server is listening:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"                        
 * Environment: production                                                        
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.                  
   Use a production WSGI server instead.                 
 * Debug mode: off                                                                   
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

My `iptables -vnL` output looks like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 11434 packets, 8571K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 7590 packets, 4856K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

so port 8000 should be good to go.
On `lsof` I can see it as well:

```
flask     16268           robin    3u  IPv4 167958      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:8000 (LISTEN)
```

I haven't really done that before, so it might be a stupid mistake, but can you think of anything else that might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The python/flask app is listening on 127.0.0.1, hence limiting access to localhost.

Make it listen on the specific IP or 0.0.0.0, depending on what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the IP manually to 0.0.0.0, so now it's listening on `http://0.0.0.0:8000/`. The requests to the IP of the machine still time out now :/
Could there be something else?